# Parse filename and rename with specific order

Tags: bash, parsing, rename

I have many `tiff` files in a directory and must rename, but there are hundreds of them and so it can be cumbersome. Files look something like this:

```
basefilename_0002_-0.0.mrc
basefilename_0003_3.0.mrc
basefilename_0004_-3.0.mrc
basefilename_0005_-6.0.mrc 
basefilename_0006_6.0.mrc 
etc...
```

All I need to do is change the middle part of the file name so that the first 41 `.mrc` files will be changes to:

```
basefilename_0001_-0.0.mrc
basefilename_0001_3.0.mrc
basefilename_0001_-3.0.mrc
basefilename_0001_-6.0.mrc 
basefilename_0001_6.0.mrc 
etc.
```

and the second 41 batch of `.mrc` files:

```
basefilename_0043_-0.0.mrc
basefilename_0044_3.0.mrc
basefilename_0045_-3.0.mrc
basefilename_0046_-6.0.mrc
basefilename_0047_6.0.mrc
```

Will be renamed to

```
basefilename_0002_-0.0.mrc
basefilename_0002_3.0.mrc
basefilename_0002_-3.0.mrc
basefilename_0002_-6.0.mrc 
basefilename_0002_6.0.mrc 
etc.
```

So essentially I have to parse after the `"basefilename_"` and before the next `"_"` and rename so that the numbers are not ascending but just 0001. But I have hundreds of these and I need to make sure that every 41 `mrc` files are the same number after the `basefile` name and before the next description.

Comment: Are you looking for a shell script?  If  so, what platform?

Comment: yes. On linux so perhaps a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do what you need using the native tools bash itself provides without relying on any separate utilities that would require spawning a separate subshell. Bash provides *parameter expansion with substring replacement* which you can use to replace the text between `_????_` with the new text you want (e.g. `0001`, ...).

Bash also provides `printf -v var` that allows you all the formatting flexibility of `man 3 print` while letting your save the formatted output in `var`. So, for example, if I have a value `1` which I want to format as `0001` and store in the variable `blkno`, it is a simple matter of `printf -v "%04d" '1'`.

Combining that with a simple counter and then using the bash provided `modulo` operator, you can do what you need with:

```
#!/bin/bash

ext=${1:-mrc}                           ## extension of files to select
declare -i blksz=${2:-41} cnt=0 blk=1   ## files per-block, counters
printf -v blkno "%04d" $blk             ## format 1st blk as 0001

for i in *.$ext; do                     ## loop over each file with extension
    ## test output showing what would be moved, to new name
    printf "mv %-28s %s\n" "$i" "${i/_*_/_${blkno}_}"
    ## mv "$i" "${i/_*_/_${blkno}_}"    ## (uncomment for actual move)
    (((cnt+1) % blksz == 0)) && {       ## check if blksz output
        ((blk++))                       ## increment blk number
        printf -v blkno "%04d" $blk     ## format as 4-digit w/leading zeros
    }
    ((cnt++))                           ## increment count
done
```

Notice the script takes as its first argument the extension of the files to loop over (default is `.mrc`) and the number of files to include in each block `41` by default.

**Example Input Files**

I didn't have your exact files, so I generated something similar with a loop and `touch`, e.g.

```
basefilename_0002_-0.0.mrc
basefilename_0003_3.0.mrc
basefilename_0004_-3.0.mrc
basefilename_0005_6.0.mrc
basefilename_0006_-6.0.mrc
basefilename_0007_9.0.mrc
basefilename_0008_-9.0.mrc
basefilename_0009_12.0.mrc
basefilename_0010_-12.0.mrc
basefilename_0011_15.0.mrc
basefilename_0012_-15.0.mrc
basefilename_0013_18.0.mrc
basefilename_0014_-18.0.mrc
basefilename_0015_21.0.mrc
basefilename_0016_-21.0.mrc
basefilename_0017_24.0.mrc
basefilename_0018_-24.0.mrc
basefilename_0019_27.0.mrc
basefilename_0020_-27.0.mrc
basefilename_0021_30.0.mrc
basefilename_0022_-30.0.mrc
basefilename_0023_33.0.mrc
basefilename_0024_-33.0.mrc
basefilename_0025_36.0.mrc
basefilename_0026_-36.0.mrc
basefilename_0027_39.0.mrc
basefilename_0028_-39.0.mrc
basefilename_0029_42.0.mrc
basefilename_0030_-42.0.mrc
basefilename_0031_45.0.mrc
basefilename_0032_-45.0.mrc
basefilename_0033_48.0.mrc
basefilename_0034_-48.0.mrc
basefilename_0035_51.0.mrc
basefilename_0036_-51.0.mrc
basefilename_0037_54.0.mrc
basefilename_0038_-54.0.mrc
basefilename_0039_57.0.mrc
basefilename_0040_-57.0.mrc
basefilename_0041_60.0.mrc
basefilename_0042_-60.0.mrc
basefilename_0043_0.0.mrc
basefilename_0044_-0.0.mrc
basefilename_0045_3.0.mrc
basefilename_0046_-3.0.mrc
basefilename_0047_6.0.mrc
basefilename_0048_-6.0.mrc
basefilename_0049_9.0.mrc
basefilename_0050_-9.0.mrc
basefilename_0051_12.0.mrc
basefilename_0052_-12.0.mrc
basefilename_0053_15.0.mrc
basefilename_0054_-15.0.mrc
basefilename_0055_18.0.mrc
basefilename_0056_-18.0.mrc
basefilename_0057_21.0.mrc
basefilename_0058_-21.0.mrc
basefilename_0059_24.0.mrc
basefilename_0060_-24.0.mrc
basefilename_0061_27.0.mrc
basefilename_0062_-27.0.mrc
basefilename_0063_30.0.mrc
basefilename_0064_-30.0.mrc
basefilename_0065_33.0.mrc
basefilename_0066_-33.0.mrc
basefilename_0067_36.0.mrc
basefilename_0068_-36.0.mrc
basefilename_0069_39.0.mrc
basefilename_0070_-39.0.mrc
basefilename_0071_42.0.mrc
basefilename_0072_-42.0.mrc
basefilename_0073_45.0.mrc
basefilename_0074_-45.0.mrc
basefilename_0075_48.0.mrc
basefilename_0076_-48.0.mrc
basefilename_0077_51.0.mrc
basefilename_0078_-51.0.mrc
basefilename_0079_54.0.mrc
basefilename_0080_-54.0.mrc
basefilename_0081_57.0.mrc
basefilename_0082_-57.0.mrc
basefilename_0083_60.0.mrc
basefilename_0084_-60.0.mrc
basefilename_0085_0.0.mrc
basefilename_0086_-0.0.mrc
basefilename_0087_3.0.mrc
basefilename_0088_-3.0.mrc
basefilename_0089_6.0.mrc
basefilename_0090_-6.0.mrc
basefilename_0091_9.0.mrc
basefilename_0092_-9.0.mrc
basefilename_0093_12.0.mrc
basefilename_0094_-12.0.mrc
basefilename_0095_15.0.mrc
basefilename_0096_-15.0.mrc
basefilename_0097_18.0.mrc
basefilename_0098_-18.0.mrc
basefilename_0099_21.0.mrc
basefilename_0100_-21.0.mrc
```

**Example Use/Output**

**note:** the actual move `mv` line is commented out to allow you to test the script and adjust as needed **before** performing the actual move. Uncomment the line beginning with `mv` when you are satisfied it performs as needed.

The script outputs file moved, the original and new filenames for the file, e.g.

```
mv basefilename_0002_-0.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_-0.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0003_3.0.mrc    basefilename_0001_3.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0004_-3.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_-3.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0005_6.0.mrc    basefilename_0001_6.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0006_-6.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_-6.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0007_9.0.mrc    basefilename_0001_9.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0008_-9.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_-9.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0009_12.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_12.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0010_-12.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-12.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0011_15.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_15.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0012_-15.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-15.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0013_18.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_18.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0014_-18.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-18.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0015_21.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_21.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0016_-21.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-21.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0017_24.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_24.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0018_-24.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-24.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0019_27.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_27.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0020_-27.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-27.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0021_30.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_30.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0022_-30.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-30.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0023_33.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_33.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0024_-33.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-33.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0025_36.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_36.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0026_-36.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-36.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0027_39.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_39.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0028_-39.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-39.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0029_42.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_42.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0030_-42.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-42.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0031_45.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_45.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0032_-45.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-45.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0033_48.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_48.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0034_-48.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-48.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0035_51.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_51.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0036_-51.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-51.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0037_54.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_54.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0038_-54.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-54.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0039_57.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_57.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0040_-57.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-57.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0041_60.0.mrc   basefilename_0001_60.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0042_-60.0.mrc  basefilename_0001_-60.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0043_0.0.mrc    basefilename_0002_0.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0044_-0.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_-0.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0045_3.0.mrc    basefilename_0002_3.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0046_-3.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_-3.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0047_6.0.mrc    basefilename_0002_6.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0048_-6.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_-6.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0049_9.0.mrc    basefilename_0002_9.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0050_-9.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_-9.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0051_12.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_12.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0052_-12.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-12.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0053_15.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_15.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0054_-15.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-15.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0055_18.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_18.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0056_-18.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-18.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0057_21.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_21.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0058_-21.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-21.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0059_24.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_24.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0060_-24.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-24.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0061_27.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_27.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0062_-27.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-27.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0063_30.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_30.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0064_-30.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-30.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0065_33.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_33.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0066_-33.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-33.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0067_36.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_36.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0068_-36.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-36.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0069_39.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_39.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0070_-39.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-39.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0071_42.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_42.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0072_-42.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-42.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0073_45.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_45.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0074_-45.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-45.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0075_48.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_48.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0076_-48.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-48.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0077_51.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_51.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0078_-51.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-51.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0079_54.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_54.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0080_-54.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-54.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0081_57.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_57.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0082_-57.0.mrc  basefilename_0002_-57.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0083_60.0.mrc   basefilename_0002_60.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0084_-60.0.mrc  basefilename_0003_-60.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0085_0.0.mrc    basefilename_0003_0.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0086_-0.0.mrc   basefilename_0003_-0.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0087_3.0.mrc    basefilename_0003_3.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0088_-3.0.mrc   basefilename_0003_-3.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0089_6.0.mrc    basefilename_0003_6.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0090_-6.0.mrc   basefilename_0003_-6.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0091_9.0.mrc    basefilename_0003_9.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0092_-9.0.mrc   basefilename_0003_-9.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0093_12.0.mrc   basefilename_0003_12.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0094_-12.0.mrc  basefilename_0003_-12.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0095_15.0.mrc   basefilename_0003_15.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0096_-15.0.mrc  basefilename_0003_-15.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0097_18.0.mrc   basefilename_0003_18.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0098_-18.0.mrc  basefilename_0003_-18.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0099_21.0.mrc   basefilename_0003_21.0.mrc
mv basefilename_0100_-21.0.mrc  basefilename_0003_-21.0.mrc
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! The test was also super useful before actual renaming.

Comment: Yes, that is always a big plus. Always write a test case that just outputs what your script will do (before actually doing it). That will allow you to verify it does what you intend -- and save you no end of grief in the event you need to tweak something... Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: I was looking back at the script. I am trying to understand the script a bit better. What does this part of the script do :%-28s %s\n . Also, Let's say I didn't want to replace the number inside the "-*_" rather I just want to put the 0001 before the 0002,0003 number that are before the .mrc file extension. How would I modify the script?

Comment: That is just a *field-width* modifier where `'-'` makes the field *left-justified*. So since the filenames were ~28-chars, I wanted them all to be 28-chars (and left justified) so the right-column was nicely formatted. The `%-28s %s\n` is just the full `printf` format string for the example output. It doesn't have any other effect on the script other than outputting what would be done. See `man 3 printf` on your system for complete details.

Comment: If you want `basefilename_-0.0_0001.mrc` instead of `basefilename_0001_-0.0.mrc`, that is doable, but will requires several additional steps since it is no longer a single *substitution*, but instead a complete reformatting of the parts of name.

Comment: basefilename_0001_-0.0.mrcok that makes sense. I meant instead of basefilename_1_0001_-0.0.mrc . So in fact no substitution just the block number before the ascending count. so output: basefilename_1_0002_-0.0.mrc
basefilename_1_0003_3.0.mrc
basefilename_1_0004_-3.0.mrc
basefilename_1_0005_6.0.mrc
basefilename_1_0006_-6.0.mrc
basefilename_1_0007_9.0.mrc
basefilename_1_0008_-9.0.mrc

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way than the following shell script to get what you want, but something like the following should work, assuming the files are sorted as needed:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

count=1
index=1

for p in *.mrc; do
    if expr $count == 42 > /dev/null; then
        index=`expr $index + 1`
        count=1
    else
        count=`expr $count + 1`
    fi

    mv $p `echo $p | sed -e "s/\(.*_\)\([0-9]*\)\(_.*\)/\1000${index}\3/"`
done
```

The `sed` command above breaks the filename `$p` into three parts found between the escaped parentheses pairs, `\( ... \)`:

- the base filename (e.g. `foo_`), retained in `\1`,
- the central digits you're modifying, replaced with `000${index}` where `${index}` expands to `1` for first set of 41 files, `2` for the second set, etc., and
- the suffix (e.g. `_3.0.mrc`), retained in `\3`

It's not a very robust implementation since you could end up with central digits like `00023` if `$index` becomes greater than `9`, but I think you get the idea for your own implementation.

Instead of `sed` you can also use Bash string manipulation builtins.  See [Section 10.1 Manipulating Strings](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html).

Comment: Your thinking is correct, and you can grab the `printf -v` trick from my answer to eliminate the possible `00023` issue. Last note would be to avoid, if possible, calling utilities with a loop in bash (e.g. `sed`). If there are 1000 files, that is 1000 calls to `sed` (and 1000 separate subshells). That will make your scripts much more efficient.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Very nice.  Your approach is far better than mine.  I learned something new, as well.  Thanks!  +1